# Why is my program outputing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

From my current understanding a segmentation fault means that something is trying to access memory that is out of that piece of codes bounds, But I can't find anything wrong with my program. I have changed a couple numbers here and there but other than that I don't even know where to begin. I am using clang on Linux x64 to compile. Sorry for my messy code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int LoopCounter;
int UsernameSize;
char Username[255];
char Request[255]="curl -o Cache -X POST https://api.random.com/profiles/randomAPI -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '[";
FILE *UsernamesFile;
FILE *OutputFile;

int main() {
  UsernamesFile = fopen("Usernames.text","r");
  OutputFile = fopen("Output.text","a");
  
  while(LoopCounter < 5) {
    for(int y=0; y < 10; y++) {
      fgets(Username, 255, UsernamesFile);
      UsernameSize = strlen(Username);
      
      for(int z=0; z < UsernameSize; z++) {
        Request[strlen(Request)-1]='"';
        Request[strlen(Request)-1+z]=Username[z];
      }
      
      Request[strlen(Request)-1]='"';
      Request[strlen(Request)-1]=',';
    }
    
    Request[strlen(Request)-2]=']';
    Request[strlen(Request)-1]='\'';
    
    for(int x=0; x < 255; x++) {
      Request[113+x]='\0';
    }
    printf("%s",Request);
  }
}
```

UPDATES: Someone suggested a debugger, really helped. Segfault seems to be from `fgets(Username, 255, UsernamesFile);` Also the last for loop deffinetly is overflowing. Which I will fix.

Problem is now (SOLVED)

Comment: Well, if either of the files fail to open you have a problem. You should add some error checking for that.

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will instantly give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Can also examine the variables and program flow as it runs.

Comment: `Request[113+x]` How's that expected to work? `x` can go up to 254 but `Request` only has 255 bytes. So will go past the end of the array. And it's always bad practice to use magic numbers like `113`.

Comment: Some of the assignments to `Request` make no sense, like the pair that assign `'"'` and `','` back-to-back to the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be solved, while my debugger said it was fgets. It was actually the last for loop which went past the array. Changed

```
for(int x=0; x < 255; x++) {
```

to

```
for(int x=0; x < 140; x++) {
```

which fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you assuming a fixed length for the user name?